# Timeseries: HBase vs OpenTSDB/KDB for range query with condition

Tags: time-series, hbase, kdb, opentsdb

I have about 100,000 users. For each user I have continuously changed (each minute) a set of values (columns) stored at HBase. Row-key look like `userId-timestamp`, where `timestamp` is rounded to minute. Dataset continuously grows, since each minute I get another 100,000 of rows.

I need low-latency query (< 0.5ms) that looks like: `(userId, fromTimestamp, toTimestamp, step)`, where `from`-`to` can contain no more than 1000 items. So I'm using HBase's range query.

The tricky part is that `step` param could have a value in [1,5,15,60,360,1440]. If `step=5`, the query should return 5th, 10th, 15th,... minute values. So `step=1440` is very expensive query.

*Can you please explain whether OpenTSDB or KDB is faster for this use case and why?*

Comment: There's a lot of questions that could be asked and a lot of unknowns but yes kdb is designed for time series and would be highly optimised for time-series-like queries (particularly when data is pre-treated with "attributes" - see https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#88-attributes ). Questions: 1 Are you saying less than 500 millis or less than 500 micros? 2. Do you have the option of embellishing the incoming data (.e.g pre-bucketing the data into steps of 5, 15, 60 etc) - this would greatly speed up later queries by bucket/step.

Comment: Question 3. When you say "60th" do you mean every 60th minute starting from the current fromTime minute, or precisely on the hour (1pm, 2pm, 3pm etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a database system for an application depends on various factors so its not that simple to answer your question.

But based on high level details that you have provided, KDB is definitely looking as one of the viable option.

**KDB** is a time series, column-oriented database. Based on your details, your application seems to have same requirements.

Your query mostly target 2 columns(userid and timestamp) and one of those columns is of time datatype. KDB has a direct support for date/time datatypes and is designed to give better performance on such data.

Generally, column oriented database would perform better than row oriented databases for these cases as they read less data and can manage and query data more efficiently as data is of uniform type for a column, so they can apply other optimizations.

**DataSize**: 100000 per minute = 6million per hour. That I would say is a medium size table from KDB perspective. KDB queries don't take much execution time on table of that size if system is designed properly.

**Attributes**: KDB also supports attributes on tables like sorted, unique, grouped and parted. Attributes help queries to perform better. For example, you could store data sorted by userid and then sorted by timestamp for each userid. Sorted attribute will make query to use binary search instead of linear search. Similarly other attributes have other useful features.

**Query Language:** Query language is an important part of any database system. KDB uses 'Q' language. It is a powerful vector language with a good collection of functions to operate on a vector.

Similarly you could query for your steps very easily in KDB. But as you have mentioned, this might be a tricky part to get the target latency. But there are various ways to design your system to improve performance for this use case.

There are other useful features in KDB to manage data like distributing data to multiple nodes, setting up different process and inter process communication.

It all comes down to how you design your system and how you organize your data into tables.

As I said at the start, selecting a database depends on various factors. I would suggest to setup KDB on your machine(its very simple) and do a test on a small set of data to get the idea.